# How can I write a SQL query to find records related to a record in another table that aren't related to another record

Tags: sql

I have a requirement to write a query that finds records related to a record in another table that **aren't** related to another record.

Below is an example of what I mean. I will happily rewrite this question and title if I can express the question in a better way (advice welcome).

Table `company`

```
id  
1
2
3
```

Table `company_partner`

```
id  company_id  company_name
1   1           Nike
2   1           Reebok
3   2           Nike
4   3           Nike
```

In the above example, I would like all companies partnered with Nike but not if they are **also** partnered with Reebok. Using the above example that would be companies `2` and `3`.

I can write a query that gives me all companies partnered with Nike:

```sql
SELECT c.id
FROM company c
INNER JOIN company_partner cp ON c.id = cp.company_id
WHERE 
    cp.company_name = 'Nike'
-- ignore cp.company_name = 'Reebok' ???
```

I am unclear how I can ignore companies that are **also** partnered with Reebok?

Comment: please add the DBMS, MSSQL, MySql ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aggregation provides one straightforward option:

```sql
SELECT company_id
FROM company_partner
GROUP BY company_id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN company_name = 'Nike' THEN 1 END) > 0 AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN company_name = 'Reebok' THEN 1 END) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use not in - like this:

```
SELECT c.id
FROM company c
INNER JOIN company_partner cp ON c.id = cp.company_id
WHERE  cp.company_name = 'Nike' 
AND c.id not in (
  select id from company_partner where company_name = 'Reebok'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply although this doesn't work because we only want to ignore company_partners 'Reebok' where also is a company_partner Nike both associated with the company. I missed that in my question, making an edit now